# Is Roma bike sharing service active?

Tags: italy, rental, bicycles, rome

I'm planning to go to Rome and get to know the city by bike.

Looking for different alternatives I've found the "ATAC bikesharing" service [here](http://www.roma-n-bike.com/) with many points where bikes can be picked up and left.

Unfortunately all the links seems to be down and last posts are from 2010. [Some sites](http://www.agenziamobilita.roma.it/it/servizi/mobilita-sostenibile/bike-sharing-roma.html) says the city bike sharing service is down but refers to it seems to be another service.

Is there any bike sharing service active in Rome or are there any alternatives?

[image]

Grazie Mille ;)

Answer (score 4):

### The service is no longer active

For more information, have a look to the aptly titled article

- [Rome Shows the World How Not to Run Bike-Sharing Program](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2014-06-11/in-eternal-city-bicycle-thieves-doom-sharing-ambitions)

also the link you provided says in bold letters

> SERVIZIO NON OPERATIVO

which literally means "service not operational" and in practice means much worse, don't ever expect that service to function again.
Also I am not aware of any other service, certainly there is nothing similar to Velib in Paris.

**Alternatively, you can try a regular bike rental**

You could try a regular bike rental. [Google gives plenty of results for that](https://www.google.com/search?q=bike%20rental%20rome).